# Combining nested conditional logical operators

Tags: nested, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I was wondering if any can help point me to resource to teach me more about logical operators, and answer a question for me. I would like (for the sake of satisfying my curiosity) to combine these nested conditional checks with logical operators into one statement.

```
if(obj1 != null && obj2 != null) {
    if(obj1 != undefined && obj2 != undefined) {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
if((obj1 != null || obj1 != undefined) && (obj2 != null || obj2 != undefined)) {
    //do something here
}
```

But I don't think that works, since if obj1 or obj2 is equal to null or undefined than the or statement will evaluate to true. So the above code in the conditional would be executed if obj1 was null or undefined AND obj2 was null or undefined, which is definitely not what I want.

So how could I combine the nested conditional into one line?

Thanks!
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be overthinking.  Code like

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

executes `stuff` only if `a` and `b` are both true, so it is simply equivalent to

```
if (a && b) {
    // stuff
}
```

Thus all you have to do is take your existing conditions and connect them with `&&`.  You can write

```
if((obj1 != null && obj2 != null) && (obj1 != undefined && obj2 != undefined)) {
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: Wow, you are right. I guess I was overthinking it haha